# Extend installed app

Tags: android

Do we have any way for adding features to an installed android application?

**For example**: I have an application with 3 features: login, searching, camera. Suppose, when user install my application, they can use only login and searching. If **they want to use camera they need to install it as plugin**. And after installed, they can use camera inside my app.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the functionality in APK and allow them to use that plugin when they select that option, you can store the selection of plugin in database to check if they have paid for camera or not

Comment: I want build a light application. User just install which features they want not full application

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at plugin technology implemented in FBReader application:

[FBReader application](https://github.com/geometer/FBReader)

[It's TTS plugin](https://github.com/geometer/FBReaderJ-plugin-tts)